# Pursuing stacks

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

What does it mean in $n$-categories the saying **pursuing stacks** ?

[image]

Comment: Google is your friend. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pursuing_Stacks#:~:text=Pursuing%20Stacks%20(French%3A%20%C3%80%20la,of%20study%20in%20algebraic%20geometry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [a manuscript by Grothendieck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pursuing_Stacks) detailing a program for developing a theory of "higher stacks" and related objects. It started off as a letter to Quillen, and an English translation can be found online [here](https://thescrivener.github.io/PursuingStacks/ps-online.pdf).

In the text quoted in the OP - Simpson's [**Homotopy theory of higher categories**](https://books.google.com/books?id=d1JTtOqBU6oC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) - the manuscript is introduced at the bottom of page $7$ *('A major turning point in the history of higher categories was Alexander Grothendieck's famous manuscript "Pursuing Stacks"...')*.

Comment: @user3357120 That's a bit technical, but you can [start at the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(mathematics)).

Comment: Why had the man whose name started at A... deleted his comment ?

Comment: @user3357120 How should I know?

Comment: My comment was addressed to him, but I have missed his name.

Comment: In fact, it is not a translation, Grothendieck wrote the manuscript in English as it grew out of the correspondence with R Brown and D Quillen in English. Now you can find here https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.01000